# Monthly free games same as ones received as PS4 collection

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, ps5

I have a PS Plus subscription on my PS5 and one of the games from PS4 you receive as a subscriber is Mortal Kombat X - the game that is this month's free game. So what's the point of that game then if you have it anyways as a subscriber?

Comment: Not everyone has been lucky enough to get a PS5 yet

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Oh, I thought these monthly games are for PS5 owners only? So PS4 owners receive one game less?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time Sony did something like that. At some point, people could get up to 6 free games per month (2 PS3 + 2 PS Vita + 2 PS4), but Sony eventually started giving [cross-buy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-buy) games. Those who owned all 3 platforms felt cheated, because they were promised 6 games (as advertised by Sony) but actually got less.

Comment: It's hard to understand PS logic: a couple of years ago one of PS+ games was Ratchet&Clank, which was then downloadable for free during "play at home" initiative last year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the official Playstation webpage](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/ps-plus/#:%7E:text=The%20PlayStation%20Plus%20Collection):

> #### The PlayStation Plus Collection
>
> Redeem and play a curated library of PS4 games that defined the generations. **Access the entire collection on your PS5.**

Emphasis mine.

Additionally, this YouTube video from the official PlayStation channel introduces the PlayStation Plus Collection as "**a new benefit for PS5**":

So the PlayStation Plus Collection is only for PS5 owners. Meanwhile, this month's Mortal Combat X is for PS4 owners.